# How to properly define a CodeMirror language?

Tags: codemirror, react-codemirror

I'm trying to provide a basic autocompletion for something like this:

```js
db.collection("Items").where("name", "==", "temp").limit(1).get();
```

Here's the code I have so far, using `StreamLanguage` of `CodeMirror 6`:

```
import {
  IndentContext,
  LanguageSupport,
  StreamLanguage,
  StringStream
} from "@codemirror/language";
import { tags as t } from "@lezer/highlight";

export const FireStoreLanguage = StreamLanguage.define({
  name: "firestore",
  startState: (indentUnit: number) => {
    return {};
  },
  token: (stream: StringStream, state: any = {}): string | null => {
    console.log(stream);
    if (stream.match("db")) {
      state.db = true;
      return "keyword";
    }
    if (stream.match(".")) {
      if (state.db) {
        state.db = false;
        state.collection = true;
        return "keyword";
      } else if (state.collection) {
        state.collection = false;
        state.where = true;
        return "keyword";
      } else if (state.where) {
        state.where = false;
        state.limit = true;
        return "keyword";
      } else if (state.limit) {
        state.limit = false;
        return "keyword";
      }
    }
    if (stream.match("collection")) {
      if (state.db) {
        state.collection = true;
        return "keyword";
      }
    }
    if (stream.match("where")) {
      if (state.collection) {
        state.where = true;
        return "keyword";
      }
    }
    if (stream.match("limit")) {
      if (state.where) {
        state.limit = true;
        return "keyword";
      }
    }
    if (stream.match("get")) {
      if (state.limit) {
        state.limit = false;
        return "keyword";
      }
    }
    if (stream.match(/"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"/)) {
      if (state.collection) {
        return "string";
      }
      if (state.where) {
        state.where = false;
        state.whereValue = true;
        return "string";
      }
      if (state.whereValue) {
        state.whereValue = false;
        return "string";
      }
      if (stream.match("==")) {
        if (state.whereValue) {
          state.whereValue = false;
          state.whereOperator = true;
          return "operator";
        }
      }
      if (stream.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
        if (state.limit) {
          return "number";
        }
      }
    }
    stream.next();
    return null;
  },
  blankLine: (state: {}, indentUnit: number): void => {},
  copyState: (state: {}) => {},
  indent: (
    state: {},
    textAfter: string,
    context: IndentContext
  ): number | null => {
    return 1;
  },
  languageData: {
    commentTokens: { line: ";" },
  },
  tokenTable: {
    db: t.keyword,
    dot: t.punctuation,
    collection: t.keyword,
    get: t.keyword,
    lParen: t.punctuation,
    rParen: t.punctuation,
    string: t.string,
  },
});

export function firestore() {
  return new LanguageSupport(FireStoreLanguage);
}
```

In React, here's how I use it(after building it):

```
import CodeMirror from "@uiw/react-codemirror";
import React from "react";
import { firestore } from "./firestore";

function App() {
  const onChange = React.useCallback((value, viewUpdate) => {
    console.log("value:", value);
  }, []);
  return (
    <CodeMirror
      value={``}
      height="100vh"
      extensions={[firestore()]}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  );
}

export default App;
```

The editor loads okay, but no autocompletion is provided while I type!

What am I doing wrong or missing in the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing these parts:

```
export const FireStoreCompletion = FireStoreLanguage.data.of({
  autocomplete: completeFromList([
    { label: "db", type: "namespace" },
    { label: "collection", type: "function" },
    { label: "where", type: "function" },
    { label: "limit", type: "function" },
    { label: "get", type: "function" },
  ]),
});
```

```
export function firestore() {
  return new LanguageSupport(FireStoreLanguage, [FireStoreCompletion]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works well, the clearest answer I've found - docs are here https://codemirror.net/docs/ref/#language.StreamParser